# Squaring inequalities with positive numbers

Tags: inequality

Basic Inequality question,

If x > 0, and y > 0, can we safely assume that if x > y, x^2 > y^2.

Thanks

Comment: For any real $x,y$ we have $x^2>y^2\iff |x|>|y|$

Comment: Note however that x^2 is not necessarily greater than y. For values of y<1, y^2<y.

Comment: @Cataline $x^2>y^2\iff x^2\ge |x|>|y|\ge y$

Comment: What about x=1/2? Then x^2<x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x>y>0$ then
$$x^2>xy>y^2>0$$

So, yes. You can assume it "safely" :)